# Expect script is not exiting with code I set it to

Tags: expect

I tried posting this in the codereview community, but there is no expect tag and I don't have enough karma to create tags.

I have written an expect script to either login to a server or run a simple (usually single) command and return the output.

I have two problems and a wish.

- Commands that return nothing--i.e., `ssh2server user host false`--time out with an error (because I'm not capturing a timeout, though I suppose I should) instead of just returning nothing.
- I can capture the return code of the program but I can't get it to exit with the appropriate code.
- Is there a way I can take the output of the called program and return it the same way (remote stdout goes to local stdout and remote stderr goes to local stderr)?

Also, any comments or (constructive) criticisms would be appreciated.

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f

 if {[info exists ::env(SSH2SERVER_PASSWORD)]} {
   set password "$env(SSH2SERVER_PASSWORD)"

 } else {
   puts "SSH2SERVER_PASSWORD not set"
   exit 1
 }

 if {[llength $argv] < 2} {
   puts "usage: ssh2server user server"
   exit 1
 }

 set user    [lindex $argv 0]
 set server  [lindex $argv 1]
 set command [lrange $argv 2 end]

 set pwd_prompt "*assword:"
 set prompt "\$ "

 set rc 0

 expect_before {
   #timeout { send_user 'timeout' ; exit 2 }
   timeout { send_user 'timeout' ; set rc 2}
 }

 log_user 0
 spawn ssh $user@$server
 expect "$pwd_prompt" { send -- "$password\r" }

 if { $command == "" } {
   interact

 } else {
   expect {
     "$prompt" {
       send -- "PROMPT_COMMAND=\rPS1='_MYPROMPT_'\r$command\r"
       #expect -re "$command\r\n(.*)\r\n\[^\r]*\[#\$%]"
       expect -re "$command\r\n(.*)\r\n\[^\r]*_MYPROMPT_"
       set results $expect_out(1,string)
       puts $results
       send -- "^D"
       expect eof
       #catch wait ec
       #set rc [lindex $ec 3]
       #puts [lindex $ec 3]
       #exit [lindex $ec 3]
     }

     #eof { send_user $expect_out(buffer); exit 3}
     eof { send_user $expect_out(buffer); set rc 3}
   }
 }

 log_user 1

 lassign [wait] pid spawnid os_flag rc
 #puts $rc # outputs correct value
 exit $rc
```

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's wrong.

Comment: Be aware that your `#eof` line is NOT a comment. `expect` takes either an even number of arguments (unusual usage) or a list with an even number of elements (typical). A Tcl comment can only appear where a command is expected.

This should not be the source of the problem, but if you see the pattern `#eof`, then you will exit 3.

Same with the expect_before line with `#timeout`

Comment: In the `$prompt` command block, those ARE comments because that block is a script.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use SSH key authentication instead of putting the password in the environment.

Comment: I can't. Company policy prevents passwordless connections to certain servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
       send -- "^D"
```

You are not sending a Ctrl-D, you are sending the characters <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>.

To send a Ctrl-D

```
       send -- "\04"
```

---

To solve the "no output, timeout" problem, you need to alter your expected regex: you have too many newlines for that case. Using `expect -d` would have revealed this to you. Like this:

```
       send -- "unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='_MYPROMPT_'\r"
       expect -re "_MYPROMPT_$"

       send -- "$command\r"
       expect -re "$command(.*)\r\n_MYPROMPT_$"
```

The content of the capturing parentheses may now be empty.

I split off setting the prompt for clarity.

---

To capture the exit status of the command, you may have to do this:

```
       send -- "$command; echo $?\r"
       expect -re "$command(.*)\r\n(\d+)\r\n_MYPROMPT_$"

       set results [regsub {^\r\n} $expect_out(1,string) ""]
       set status $expect_out(2,string)
```

---

I don't *think* you can separate stdout and stderr with the `expect` command. I think both streams are captured as "output". (I don't have my Exploring Expect book nearby to confirm)

If that's important, you might want to invoke the command redirecting stdout and/or stderr to file(s), and then `cat` and capture the file contents.

Comment: That's the way it copy-n-pasted. I'm sending the actual control character. However, I changed the code and saw no changes. I also removed all the comments, just in case. It made no difference.

Comment: It would be more clear to another person if you sent `exit` instead of a control code.

Comment: Using 'exit' causes the script to timeout.

Comment: Thank you ... I was getting `can't read "command(.*)": variable isn't array` so I changed your solution to `expect -re "${command}(.*)\r\n$myprompt"`. Now both null returns and data is being returned.

Comment: Very minor complaint ... I'm getting an extra blank line in the beginning of the output (`false` returns null so there is no blank line and 'who am i' produces  correct output but with blank line). If I move the `\r\n` to right before the capture then it just moves the blank line to the end of the output. I've tried `[\r\n]*`, `[\r\n]+`, `(?:\r\n)?` and couple of other permutations, but they all cause the program to exit with `invalid command name "
"`

Comment: If I uncomment the `puts $rc` line, it prints the correct exit status, but the exit status is not being set. Even if I hard code the exit line to, e.g., `exit 42` the exit status is still 0 when the script exits.

Comment: Btw, I marked this as answered because the main problem (null output not being handled) is fixed. The rest is just cosmetic--well, the exit code would really help but it's workable.

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between exiting the remote shell and exiting from expect.

Comment: The last three lines of what I pasted should take care of that, shouldn't it? The wait command waits for the remote to close, returns the exit status of the remote command in the 3rd element, which I'm assigning to a variable and then setting the exit command (not sending exit to the remote). No matter the result of the command, and even though the puts command is printing the correct exit status, the script exits with 0 exit status. Debugging does not show any relevant (as I understand it) information.

Comment: Well, you're relying on the remote shell exiting with the status of its last command, and ssh exiting with the status of its remote shell. I wonder if the `ssh` command in your script is actually a wrapper around the *real* ssh executable, and that wrapper does not pass along the exit status.